# Tomcat 8 Oracle 11 JNDI Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'

Tags: oracle, datasource, jndi, tomcat8, spring-4

I'm trying to set up a Spring 4 MVC application in STS using a Tomcat 8 server and an Oracle 11g database, and I'm having problems setting up the datasource.

I know there's nothing wrong with the Spring setup because, without the datasource, it works fine.

Here's the datasource bean:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/myDB" />
    <property name="resourceRef" value="false" />
</bean>
```

My web.xml resource ref:

```
<resource-ref>
   <res-ref-name>jdbc/myDB</res-ref-name>
   <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
   <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

My Tomcat's server.xml resources:

-->

```
<Resource name="jdbc/myDB"
          global="jdbc/myDB"
          auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          username="xxxxx"
          password="yyyyyy"
          url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxx.yyy"
          driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
          initialSize="20"
          maxWaitMillis="15000"
          maxTotal="75"
          maxIdle="20"
          maxAge="7200000"
          testOnBorrow="true"
          validationQuery="select 1 from dual"
          />
```

And my context.xml

```
  <ResourceLink name="jdbc/myDB"
    global="jdbc/myDB"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
```

The error I'm getting is this:

> ERROR: Unable obtain JDBC Connection java.sql.SQLException: Cannot
>   create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2167)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2037)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1543)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl$1.obtainConnection(SessionFactoryImpl.java:419)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.spi.id.IdTableHelper.executeIdTableCreationStatements(IdTableHelper.java:67)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.spi.id.global.GlobalTemporaryTableBulkIdStrategy.finishPreparation(GlobalTemporaryTableBulkIdStrategy.java:125)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.spi.id.global.GlobalTemporaryTableBulkIdStrategy.finishPreparation(GlobalTemporaryTableBulkIdStrategy.java:42)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.spi.id.AbstractMultiTableBulkIdStrategyImpl.prepare(AbstractMultiTableBulkIdStrategyImpl.java:88)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:302)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:445)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:710)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:511)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:495)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:742)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:138)
>     at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1183)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1099)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:989)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4940)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5250)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: java.sql.SQLException:
>   No suitable driver    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2151)
>     ... 44 more

My Tomcat lib directory has the ojdbc jar that I need,  and I've even included it on my build script. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Check your connection URL.  Also, always use the long form of the connection URL where you could pass various connection descriptors.

Example: jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(HOST=myhost)(PORT=1521)(PROTOCOL=tcp))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=myorcldbservicename)))

Answer (score 0):

The solution was as simple as it was embarrassingly stupid. Since I was working in Eclipse, Eclipse generates and uses its own server.xml and context.xml documents in a Servers directory. Once I put my datasource into those files, everything worked fine